# How do you fix the error: cannot find git command?

Tags: python, git, pip

I am trying to update Theanos module from github using pip installer. But, I'm getting an cmd error saying that 'cannot find git command.' Here's what I've tried and the photo below shows it. I read that the problem occurs when git isn't in the Windows path, so I tried doing it to my best knowledge. But, I'm still running into a trouble here. Let me know what you all think. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you probably need to add git\bin to path, not just git or git\cmd

Comment: Still not being recognized despite the addition...

Comment: you restarted cmd?

Comment: iced - Yup that was the fix. Thank you!